# Download the HTML template page filled with Django form

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a template page on which one I access when I filled my `Django form`. This page is a simple `HTML page` with data coming from my form. I would like to be able to download the filled template. That's to say, get a browser window which let to download the template or by clicking on a button which will save the HTML template somewhere (because this HTML template need to be insert in mailing).

This is my code in my **views.py** file:

```
class TemplateGenerator(TemplateView):
    ''' This class displays the form and lets to save data into my database.
        It redirects users to the filled HTML template '''
    form_class = CommunicationForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = '/HTML_Result/'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('HTML_Result')
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)


class HTMLResult(TemplateView):
    ''' This class displays the template filled thanks to the form from TemplateGenerator() class '''
    template_name = 'template_1.html'

    def get(self, request):
        data = Communication.objects.values().latest('id')
        self.donwload_html()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'data': data})

    def donwload_html(self):
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media')
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read(),
                                        content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + 'test'
                return response
        raise Http404
```

I got a permission denied with `file_path` when I try to access to the media folder.
But to my mind, my function is maybe false compared to what I would like to get.

Do you have any idea ?

I know I need to use `Content-Disposition` in order to download the HTML page, but I don't find a way to use it correctly.

Thank you by advance

Comment: Instead of downloading the filled template, you can actually create a view that uses the template and data to create a filled html template to send in an email. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: @rchurch4 Thnak you for your answer. In a first time, I don't need to create an email sending function. It should be in the second phasis. My question is : How I can download the filled template ?

Comment: I don't believe that that function really exists in Django. It's not in the business of creating things and saving them so much as it's in the business of creating things and sending them (to web browser, api users, etc.).  You could, however, use the django `render_to_string` function, and then save the string to a file. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string